Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs'
I am trying to install Nest CLI globally using npm.
I am using MacOS Ventura.
What i write in my terminal is $ npm install -g @nestjs/cli.
This the error i get.
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs'
I just want to install Nest CLI for my first nest API project.

npm install -g requires super user permissions ...

what do I have to do?

I'm not a mac user, but on linux it would be sudo npm install -g
